# How to suppress single MISRA 2004 Rule for symbol in PC lint

Tags: c, static-analysis, misra, pc-lint

I'm linting below code snippet at [online demonstration website of PC-Lint](http://gimpel-online.com//cgi-bin/genPage.py?srcFile=diy.c&cgiScript=analyseCode.py&title=Do-It-Yourself+Example+%28C%29&intro=This+example+allows+you+to+specify+your+own+C+code.&compilerOption=online32.lnt&includeOption=%7B%7BquotedIncludeOption%7D%7D) with enabled MISRA 2004 checkings

```
    #include <stdint.h>

    //enable some of MISRA 2004 Rules
    //lint +e960
    
    static uint8_t printf_(uint8_t a, void * b, ...);
    static uint8_t printf_(uint8_t a, void * b, ...)
    {
      (void) a;
      (void) b;
      return 0U;
    }
    
    static const uint8_t (*func)(uint8_t a, void * b, ...) = printf_;
    
    int main(void)
    {
      uint8_t data[8U] = {0};
      (void) func(1U, &data[0], 2U);
      return 0;
    }
```

PC Lint then tells me that I have following violations of MISRA 2004 Rules:

> Note 960:  Violates MISRA 2004 Required Rule 16.1, function has variable number of arguments: `printf_`
>
> Note 960:  Violates MISRA 2004 Required Rule 16.9, function identifier used without '&' or parenthesized parameter list: `printf_`

How to suppress only MISRA 2004 Rule 16.1 for function `printf_`?
Until now I've tried following solutions, none of below work for me:

- `-esym(960, 16.1)` suppresses MISRA Rule 16.1 for all other symbols
- `-estring(960, "printf_")` suppresses all other MISRA Rules for `printf_` symbol e.g. Rule 16.9
- `-estring(960, "function has variable number of arguments: 'printf_'")` according to manual suppose to work, but I cannot make it happen
- `-estring(960, "function has variable number of arguments:", "printf_")` some experimental hint from following website [Matthias Kraaz' blog](https://matthiaskraaz.blogspot.com/2015/12/pc-lint-using-estring-to-suppress-misra.html) also doesn't work

The best which I got for now is:

- putting `printf_` in block of `-esym(960, 16.1) ... +esym(960, 16.1)`, this however elevates MISRA 2004 warnings to the error level and stops compilation if another violation is going to happen.

I'm looking forward for your ideas.

Comment: Aside: To quiet 16.9, Try `static const uint8_t (*func)(uint8_t a, void * b, ...) = &printf_;`  (Added &)

Comment: Thanks for answer, however this error was done on purpose by me. In order to have two MISRA 2004 rules violations.

Comment: Have you tried: `-esym(960, printf_)`?